# "unrecognized token" with special characters

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

I work with SQLite and Xamarin for iOS.
I have a problem with creating a correct query string. I think the problem is special characters in the string.
I have given a brand name and I will select this in the DB:

This works for Strings without special characters like: "BESSEY" but for strings like "ALURIX® 600" it does not work.

```
return dbConn.Query<MasterProductDataStructure>("SELECT * FROM ZMASTERPRODUCTS WHERE ZMANUFACTURER='" + ZBRANDS + "'");
```

Error message:

> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ""ALUTRIX® 600"

Then I test:

```
return dbConn.Query<MasterProductDataStructure>("SELECT * FROM ZMASTERPRODUCTS WHERE ZMANUFACTURER=\"" + ZBRANDS + "\"");
```

Error message:

> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: ""ALUTRIX® 600"

The full Method:

```
public List<MasterProductDataStructure> GetAllProductBrands(string ZBRANDS )
{
      return dbConn.Query<MasterProductDataStructure>("SELECT * FROM ZMASTERPRODUCTS WHERE ZMANUFACTURER=\"" + ZBRANDS + "\"");
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a possible solution:

```
return dbConn.Query<MasterProductDataStructure>("SELECT * FROM ZMASTERPRODUCTS WHERE ZMANUFACTURER= ?", ZBRANDS);
```